# Unable to build android studio project with Kotlin compiler while creating composite primary key in room version 1.1.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2

While I am creating an 'Entity' with a 'primaryKey' annotation over a field to create any SQLite table using room, the Android Studio project builds successfully. But while I am trying to create an 'Entity' with composite primary key, unable to build the project.
Unfortunately as I am using 'Dagger 2' in my project unable to see the actual build error.

**Note**: Project complies with Kotlin compiler.

**Code**:

```
@Entity(tableName = "thread_users", primaryKeys = {"thread_id", "user_id"})
public class DMThreadUsers {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "thread_id")
    private String threadId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_left")
    private boolean isLeft;

    public DMThreadUsers() {
    }

    public String getThreadId() {
        return threadId;
    }

    public void setThreadId(String threadId) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public boolean isLeft() {
        return isLeft;
    }

    public void setLeft(boolean left) {
        isLeft = left;
    }
}
```

Comment: please refer to this link for composite primary key . that is not the way . 

https://medium.com/@KinneraPriyaP/entity-embedded-and-composite-primary-keys-with-room-db-8cb6ca6256e8

Comment: The issue got resolved after doing the followings.

1. Added '@NonNull' annotation on composite key fields.
2. In '@Dao' the parameters for insert operation was wrong.

But it is very unfortunate that Android Studio/Kotlin compiler is unable to point the exact error at the time of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key fields should be annotated with @NonNull. You have to annotate @NonNull in JAVA for primary key fields and in KOTLIN one need to initialise the primary key fields.

```
@Entity(tableName = "thread_users", primaryKeys = {"thread_id", "user_id"})
public class DMThreadUsers {
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "thread_id")
    private String threadId;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_left")
    private boolean isLeft;

    public DMThreadUsers() {
    }

    public String getThreadId() {
        return threadId;
    }

    public void setThreadId(String threadId) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public boolean isLeft() {
        return isLeft;
    }

    public void setLeft(boolean left) {
        isLeft = left;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue got resolved after doing the followings.

1. Added '@NonNull' annotation on composite key fields.
2. In '@Dao' the parameters for insert operation was wrong.

But it is very unfortunate that Android Studio/Kotlin compiler is unable to point the exact error at the time of compilation.